# Compare NSDates of two Different NSArrays

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsdate

I have two `NSArrays` and both of them have different keys for their JSON created at value. The first array is a list of Twitter tweets and the `NSDate` key for each object is the `created_at` value. The other `NSArray` I have is a list of Instagram Pictures and the `NSDate` value for the object is `created_time`. How would I put both of these arrays into another `NSArray` and sort every value based on the time of the object? How would I put both the arrays into an `NSDictionary` of the same specifications stated before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining two arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *combinedArr = [[originalArray1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray: 
    originalArray2] mutableCopy];
```

---

To sort an `NSMutableArray`:

- Write a method that will return an `NSComparisonResult` to describe how the objects you're sorting should be sorted.  If you're using something like `NSDate`, there's probably already a method written that'll do this for you.
- With that method written, in hand, and ready to go, sort the array:

> ```
> [arrToBeSorted sortUsingSelector:@selector(yourSortMethod:)];
> ```

An example on putting together the sorting method:

First, you need to return `NSComparisonResult`.  And the argument you need to accept should be an object of the same class for which you're calling the method on (we're comparing Object A with Object B, both of same class.  And finally, you'll put logic in the method to determine what `NSComparisonResult` to return.

```
-(NSComparisonResult)compareObjects:(MyObjectClass*)objectB {
    // pseudo code:
    if(self comes before objectB) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if(self comes after objectB) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

`NSOrderedAscending` says when I do `[objectA compareObjects: objectB];`, that A comes before B with this logic.  So a sort using `[arrToBeSorted sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareObjects:)];` would return the array with `objectA` in an index smaller than `objectB`.

`NSOrderedDescending` would do just the opposite.

`NSOrderedSame` says that for this comparison, these two objects are equivalent, so it doesn't matter whether the order is `objectA`,`objectB`, or `objectB`,`objectA`, so when compared, the two objects will never trade places.  If they're put in an array with `objectC` or `objectD`, then A and B will sorted around into the right order relative to C and D, but A and B won't be swapped with each other because `NSOrderedSame` says that their order, relative to each other, does not matter.

And that's all you're doing with an `NSComparisonResult`.  You're returning a value that tells the caller how these two objects should be sorted relative to each other.  The `NSMutableArray` method `sortUsingSelector:` using the given selector and iterates through all the objects to get them all in the right order, so for EVERY object in the array, everything before it would return `NSOrderedDescending` or `NSOrderedSame` for the given `selector` the array was sorted with, and everything after it would return `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedSame`.

*** As a note, for this to work appropriately, everything in the array needs to respond to the sorting selector with the same logic.  If you write a method `orderByDate` that sorts by some `object.date` property, that's fine, as long as every object in the array has the `orderByDate` method (and the same logic in it), the `.date` property, and they'll all respond in a logical way.  If you throw an `NSString` in there, you'll have problems (run time exception).  If `[objectA compareObjects:objectB]` returns `NSOrderedAscending`, then `[objectB compareObjects: objectA];`must return `NSOrderedDescending`.

---

For putting them into a dictionary, you're going to have to be more clear on the intended structure of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you want. The following is an approach.

1. Create classes for Tweet and Instagram Picture
2. Write an adapter method to return the item's created date

   Class: Tweet

   ```
   - (NSDate *)createdDate {
     return self.created_at;
   }
   ```

   Class: InstagramPicture

   ```
   - (NSDate *)createdDate {
     return self.created_time;
   }
   ```
3. Combine both input arrays

   ```
   NSMutableArray *combinedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [combinedArray addObjectsFromArray:tweets];
   [combinedArray addObjectsFromArray:instagramPictures];
   ```
4. Sort the combined array by comparator

   ```
   NSArray *sortedCombinedArray = [combinedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
      return [obj1.createdDate compare:obj2.createdDate];
   }];
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As *nhgrif* said Combine two arrays by:

```
NSMutableArray *combinedArr = [[originalArray1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray: 
    originalArray2] mutableCopy];
```

And for sorting array

```
-(NSMutableArray *)sortArrayBasedOndate:(NSMutableArray *)combinedArr
{
    NSDateFormatter *fmtDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmtDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSDateFormatter *fmtTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [fmtTime setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    NSComparator compareDates = ^(id string1, id string2)
    {
        NSDate *date1 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string1];
        NSDate *date2 = [fmtDate dateFromString:string2];

        return [date1 compare:date2];
    };

    NSComparator compareTimes = ^(id string1, id string2)
    {
        NSDate *time1 = [fmtTime dateFromString:string1];
        NSDate *time2 = [fmtTime dateFromString:string2];

        return [time1 compare:time2];
    };

    NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"start_date" ascending:YES comparator:compareDates];
    NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc2 = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"starts" ascending:YES comparator:compareTimes];
    [combinedArr sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDesc1, sortDesc2]];

    return combinedArr;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: The problem is that you're sending an object a message it can't respond to. In this case, it looks like  StreamViewController can't respond to the message sortArrayBasedOndate:. Use breaK points and logs there and find out where it crashing.